# Java Apache Spark RDD persist

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have some code like this:

```
JavaPairRDD A = JavaPairRDD B;
B.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK())
```

Later, variable A might or might not be reassigned to the transformation from another JavaPairRDD. If A is not reassigned, will Spark know that it should leverage what B persists in memory when A needs to be transformed?